# Approve post directly from preview mode?

Tags: previews

How do I approve a post directly from preview mode, instead of having 
to return to edit mode and/or "list of posts" mode?

I'm script-matically uploading several (hundred) posts, but want to 
live preview them briefly before approval.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is something i have laying around:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Approve From preview
Plugin URI: http://en.bainternet.info
Description: Approve from privew  is Plugin that lets yo approve posts (draft and pending) from the preview itself.
Version: 0.1
Author: Bainternet
License:

  Copyright 2012 Bainternet (admin@bainternet.info)

  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License, version 2, as 
  published by the Free Software Foundation.

  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
  GNU General Public License for more details.

  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
  along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
  Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA

*/
if (!class_exists('ApproveFromPreview')){

        class ApproveFromPreview {
                /**
                 * Constructor
                 */
                function __construct() {
                    //create approve link
                    add_filter('the_content',array($this,'add_approve_button'));
                    add_filter('the_content',array($this,'show_approved'));

                    //create message
                    add_action('wp',array($this,'approve_post'));
                }

                /**
                 * add_approve_button  shows a link when in preview
                 * @param  string $content 
                 * @return string 
                 */
                public function add_approve_button($content){
                    global $post;
                    if (is_preview() &&  
                        current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post->ID ) &&  
                        current_user_can( 'publish_posts', $post->ID ) &&
                        in_array($post->post_status,array('draft', 'pending'))
                    ){
                        return $this->get_button().$content;
                    }

                    return $content;
                }

                /**
                 * show_approved shows a message if approved or not
                 * @param  string $content 
                 * @return string 
                 */
                public function show_approved($content){
                    //show fail success message
                    $msg = '';
                    if ( isset( $_GET['msg'] ) ){
                        if( $_GET['msg'] == 'approved' ) 
                            $con =  '<div class="success" style="background: #1599CC;padding: 3px;border-radius: 10px;">' . __( 'Post Approved' ) . '</div>';
                        else
                            $con =  '<div class="error" style="background: #CC1515;padding: 3px;border-radius: 10px;">' . __( 'Post not Approved' ) . '</div>';
                    }
                    return $con . $content;
                }

                public function get_button(){
                    global $post;
                    return '<a href="'.wp_nonce_url( "?action=AFP&pid=" . $post->ID, 'AFP_NONCE').'" class="button">'.__('Approve').'</a><br/>';
                }

                /**
                 * approve_post if needed this plugin will call the approval action and 
                 * redirect to the newly approved post with a message.
                 * @return Void
                 */
                public function approve_post(){
                    if (!isset($_REQUEST['_wpnonce']) || 
                        !isset($_REQUEST['pid']) || 
                        !isset( $_REQUEST['action']) || 
                        $_REQUEST['action'] != "AFP" )
                    {
                        return;
                    }

                    $nonce = $_REQUEST['_wpnonce'];
                    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'AFP_NONCE' ) ) {
                        return; 
                    }
                    $pid = intval($_REQUEST['pid']);
                    if (current_user_can( 'edit_post',$pid ) && current_user_can( 'publish_posts', $pid )){
                        $p = $this->change_post_status($pid,'publish');
                        if ($p > 0){
                            $redirect = add_query_arg( array('msg' => 'approved'), get_permalink($p) );
                            wp_redirect( $redirect );
                            exit;
                        }else{
                            $redirect = add_query_arg( array('msg' => 'not_approved'), get_permalink() );
                            wp_redirect( $redirect );
                            exit;
                        }
                        return;
                    }
                    return;
                }

                /**
                * the function that will actually change the post status
                * $post_id - The ID of the post you'd like to change.
                * $status -  The post status publish|pending|draft|private|static|object|attachment|inherit|future|trash.
                */
                /**
                 * change_post_status description
                 * @param  int $post_id  post id
                 * @param  string $status  new status
                 * @return int 1 if successfully  0  if not :)
                 */
                public function change_post_status($post_id,$status){
                    $current_post = get_post( $post_id, 'ARRAY_A' );
                    $current_post['post_status'] = $status;
                    return wp_update_post($current_post);
                }



        } // end class
}//end if
new ApproveFromPreview();
```

i haven't tested in it a while but it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

What ever happened to just CTRL-click the "Preview" button so you get the preview in another window/tab of your browser? Then just CTRL-W to close the preview tab and then hit your Publish button.

Okay, low tech solution, and Bainternet's solution definitely rocks. Just thought I'd put it out there...

Comment: Too many clicks :) Actually, that's what I meant by "list of posts" mode. I'm reviewing literally 1000s of posts, and every click counts.